# Can I instruct Solr (Sunspot) to skip reindexing for a block of code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I'd like to run a series of interactions with various `Searchable` model records and not reindex any of the models until all of my interactions are completed. Is this possible?

I know I can manually call the reindexing method, but how do I manually instruct Sunspot to *not* reindex for a given block of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

johnnycakes's answer was helpful, but since I needed to prevent automatic indexing entirely for a given model, I used the following instead:

```
searchable :auto_index => false do
  text :name
  text :description
  # etc...
end
```

The `:auto_index => false` part is what instructs Solr to not index the model. Straightforward - but for some reason this took me a while to find via Google.

Answer (score 4):

```
Sunspot.session = Sunspot::Rails::StubSessionProxy.new(Sunspot.session)
# whatever code you want to execute and not trigger a reindex
Sunspot.session = Sunspot.session.original_session
```

References:

[link1](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/ruby-sunspot/disable%2420index/ruby-sunspot/BRB4RZbl3jk/oLpHfmS3d0kJ)

[link2](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/RSpec-and-Sunspot)